# Is it possible to 'spoof' an Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, crosswalk

I am trying to replace the native WebView within our app with Crosswalk's XWalkView.  The issue is that in our Services a WebView can be created without an Activity using a window manager.  Crosswalk does not support this and it seems that if we are going to accomplish this, then we need to be able to spoof an Activity/Context that can be passed to the XWalkView constructor or we need to be able to create an Activity that will in no way interrupt the user..

I am fairly new to developing in Android, is this something that is possible?

Thanks,
Jonathon

Comment: You can create a transparent Activity or use a Service and use mWindowManager.addView(mFloatLayout, wmParams) to create a float window.

Comment: inflate it from xml, seems no activity is needed.
`public XWalkView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`

Comment: I don't think it is possible since I need to override some of the XWalkView methods.  Is there a way to save a context from an activity? I tried to save it in a holder class, then use it in the service but the context is null, even if the activity was launched just a few moments ago.

Comment: @JGray We've done something similar - do confirm if this works in theory for you and I can post an answer :)

1.) Create a new Activity
2.) Override onAttachedToWindow for zero-height
3.) Use as Context to profit

Comment: I'm one of the developer of Crosswalk. Currently, XWalkView is forced to be bundled with singe activity, it doesn't support services and can not even be shared across multiple activities. However, we've noticed developer's needs and decoupling XWalkView from activity will be our priority in next version's development.